# Is there a good tutorial on Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a good tutorial overview on how to use Google calendar effectively?  I am most interested in using it to coordinate multiple calendars for family and work group members, as well as syncing with various devices.

Answer (score 2):

[Google's official resources](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/?hl=en) are very helpful. Especially if you're having trouble with something in particular.

Just remember that the site was designed to be intuitive and not complicated. It shouldn't require an in-depth tutorial to get started. For me personally, I just started using it and whenever I had something I needed more information about, I just referred to Google's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is [series of video tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qsZUbVqUZc&feature=PlayList&p=86393B62706987AD&playnext_from=PL&playnext=1&index=3) on YouTube on using it.